# How to iterate through complex object in Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

I have a Typescript object declared like this:

```
export class MockData {
    public static food = {
        "cake": {
            "name": "donut",
            "price": "1.5€",
            "ingredients": {
                "base": "biscuit",
                "batter": [{
                    "id": "1002",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1003",
                    "type": "Blueberry"
                }
                ],
                "toppings": [{
                    "id": "5002",
                    "type": "Glazed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5004",
                    "type": "Maple"
                }
                ]
            },
            "baking_time": "2h"
        }
    };
}
```

Then, from another class, I want to iterate through `ingredients`property to access `base`, `batter` and `toppings` as if they were also objects (to be able to access `batter` elements the same way). I have tried this:

```
Object.keys(MockData.food.cake).forEach( element => {
        console.log(element);
});
```

and also:

```
for(let prop in MockConversation.conversation.cake){
    if(1){ // Test condition
        console.log(prop);
    }
}
```

But with this, I can only obtain `name`, `price`, `ingredients` and `baking_time` as strings, so I can't access their internal properties. What could I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this loop, you iterate on keys. So when logging it, it shows the key itself. If you want the value, you can achieve it like that :

```
Object.keys(MockData.food.cake).forEach(key => {
        console.log(MockData.food.cake[key]);
});
```

this way, you will get : `donut`, `1.5€`, `2h` and the ingredients list as an object :

```
{
    "base": "biscuit",
    "batter": [{
        "id": "1002",
        "type": "Chocolate"
    },
    {
        "id": "1003",
        "type": "Blueberry"
    }
    ],
    "toppings": [{
        "id": "5002",
        "type": "Glazed"
    },
    {
        "id": "5004",
        "type": "Maple"
    }
    ]
}
```

but if you want to access to `base`, `batter` and `toppings` and if your data structure permits it maybe it's easier to access directly :

```
const ing = MockData.food.cake.ingredients;

console.log(ing.base);

Object.keys(ing.batter).forEach(key => {
        console.log(ing.batter[key]);
});

Object.keys(ing.toppings).forEach(key => {
        console.log(ing.toppings[key]);
});
```

output :

```
biscuit
{id: "1002", type: "Chocolate"}
{id: "1003", type: "Blueberry"}
{id: "5002", type: "Glazed"}
{id: "5004", type: "Maple"}
```